# DataHandler for SOAP Binary Data in Linux Environment

Tags: java, unix, soap, datahandler

I have a webapp which calls a soap service.

The soap service receives XML data in binary format and below is the code in one of the classes given by ws-import

```
@XmlElement(name = "Binary")
@XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")
protected DataHandler binary;
```

In my client, I'm having below line of code

```
content.setBinary(new DataHandler(xmlString, "text/plain"));
```

When I deploy my app in liberty (web container) on my windows laptop it just works fine. XML data is sent as binary in SOAP request. But when the application is deployed to liberty in linux box, it doesn't work. The soap request received on the server doesn't show the binary data

I tried setting the mime type as "text/xml" and "application/octet-stream" but nothing helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per below link I was able to send the data as FileURI and it worked

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/102577